# How can I capture and print packets from the internet on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, packets

How can I capture them? 
Is there any module/lib to do it?

Please if it do, post an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can install [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), you can [use it programaticaly from Python](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Python). (This isn't *yet* supported on Windows, as per [bug 3500](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=3500).)

---

You also have [PyCap](http://pycap.sourceforge.net/), a Python Packet Capture and Injection Library that seems to be platform independent.

---

Yet another packet sniffing module is [Scapy](http://trac.secdev.org/scapy/wiki/WindowsInstallationGuide), that I though didn't work on Windows, but was fortunately mistaken.